# Average function of the first n-decimal digits.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, probability-theory

I am teaching myself analysis using the Thomson Bruckner and Bruckner book. It is available online here:
http://classicalrealanalysis.info/com/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Portrait.pdf

The problem image:
[image]

Here is the main statement of the problem:

We construct a function with IVP (Intermediate Value Property) whose graph may be difficult to visualize. Let $I_o=(0,1)$. Each $x$ has a unique decimal expansion not ending in a string of 9's. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x =a_1 a_2 \cdots$ in $I_o$, let $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_1^n a_i(x)$. Thus $f_n(x)$  represents the average of the first $n$ digits of $x$. For each $x \in I_o$, let $f(x) = \limsup_n f_n(x)$

1. Show that $f: I_o \mapsto [1,10]$.
2. Describe how to construct $x \in I_o$ such that $f(x) = \pi$.
3. Describe how to construct $x \in (.01, .02)$ such that $f(x) = \pi$.

I can see how the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = 10^{-n}$ maps to $0$. However, that rest of the questions have stumped me.

1. I do not see how $\limsup_n f_n(x)$ can ever be 10. I would have thought that $f:I_o \mapsto [0,9]$, but $[0,10]$. The average cannot be larger than the components $\{0, \cdots, 9\}$.
2. I do not know how to approach this problem. I see that each digit has to appear infinitely many times to even contribute to the average. Any finitely occurring digit will have its contribution tend to 0. Since if the proportion of the digits occurring for number sequence of length $n$ is denoted by $p_{n_0}, \cdots, p_{n_9}$ substituting into $f(x)$,

$f(x) = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} sup \frac{p_{n_1} + 2 p_{n_2} + 3 p_{n_3} + \cdots + 9 p_{n_9}}{n}$

Sounds like an extremely interesting result if Only I can figure out how to construct $\pi$ and the rest of the stuff.

Any help would be much appreciated. Even if clues are provided, references or whatever. I thank you very much for you answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first point is correct.  The range of $f$ is $[0,9]$

For 2, we can just create the decimal place by place.  Start with $x_1=0.3$.  If $f_k(x_k) \lt \pi$ append a $4$ to get $x_k+1$.  If $f_k(x_k) \gt \pi$ append a $3$ to get $x_{k+1}$.  Let $x=\lim_k x_k$.  We will have $f_n(x) \to \pi$.  For 3, your intuition that the first few places don't matter is correct, so just subtract $0.2$ from the $x$ we found.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I eventually figured it out as well, it was a bit anti-climactic, but it was interesting to realize that it was just a matter of figuring out the proportion of 3's and 4's since $3 < \pi < 4$. We can mix any other integers we want as long as there are finitely many. One thing is for sure, it is really a bizarre function.

Comment: You can use any digits you want as long as you have some $3$ or below and some $4$ or above.  Just use the small ones when you are too high and large ones when you are too low.

Comment: Yep I got that as well... I could not help but think of interpolation after getting a hang of it. Thanks again. That was edifying.